# Как загрузить на сервер файл используя пакет multipart в Go?

Tags: golang, upload, multipart

Аналогичный скрипт на Python загружает файл на яндекс без всяких вопросов. Там я даже никаких заголовков не указывал

```
files = {"file": (
        os.path.basename(filepath), 
        open(filepath, 'rb'), 
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
        )
    }

resp = requests.post(url, params=params, files=files)
```

однако весьма подробный вариант на Go серверу яндекса не нравится:

Ответ яндекса: {
"error": "BadArgument",
"description": "Bad argument: file"
}

Сабж.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "os"
    "io"
    "time"
    "strings"
    "compress/gzip"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http" 
    "net/url"
    "net/textproto"
    "mime/multipart"
    "path/filepath"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func FatalIfErr(format string, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(format, err.Error())
    }
}

func Unzip(resp *http.Response) (io.ReadCloser, error) {
    var err error
    var body = resp.Body
    if resp.Header.Get("Content-Encoding") == "gzip" &&
        resp.Request.Header.Get("Accept-Encoding") != "" {
        reader, err := gzip.NewReader(body)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        body = reader
    }
    return body, err
}

var quoteEscaper = strings.NewReplacer("\\", "\\\\", `"`, "\\\"")

func escapeQuotes(s string) string {
    return quoteEscaper.Replace(s)
}

// CreateFormFile is a convenience wrapper around CreatePart. It creates
// a new form-data header with the provided field name and file name.
func CreateFormFile(
        w *multipart.Writer, 
        fieldname, filename, contentType string,
    ) (io.Writer, error) {
    
    h := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
    h.Set("Content-Disposition",
        fmt.Sprintf(`form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"`,
            escapeQuotes(fieldname), escapeQuotes(filename)))
    h.Set("Content-Type", contentType)
    return w.CreatePart(h)
}

func Upload(urlPath string, queryValues *url.Values, filePath string) ([]byte, error){
    var err error
    var result []byte
    
    file, _ := os.Open(filePath)
    defer file.Close()

    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    //fw, _ := writer.CreateFormFile("file", filepath.Base(filePath))
    fw, _ := CreateFormFile(
        writer, 
        "file", 
        filepath.Base(filePath), 
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    )
      
    io.Copy(fw, file) // dest, src
    writer.Close()

    r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", urlPath, body)
    r.URL.RawQuery = queryValues.Encode()
    r.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    r.Header.Set("Accept", "*/*")
    r.Header.Set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
    r.Header.Set("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7")
    r.Header.Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    r.Header.Set("Connection","keep-alive")
    r.Header.Set("Origin","https://translate.yandex.ru")
    r.Header.Set("Referer", "https://translate.yandex.ru/doc")
    r.Header.Set("Pragma", "no-cache")
    r.Header.Set("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty")
    r.Header.Set("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors")
    r.Header.Set("Sec-Fetch-Site", "cross-site")
    
    // for debug
    fmt.Printf("ContentType: %s\n", writer.FormDataContentType())
    fmt.Printf("REQUEST: %#v\n",r)
    fmt.Printf("REQUEST URL:%s\n", r.URL.String())
    
    timeout := time.Duration(5 * time.Second)
    client := &http.Client{Timeout: timeout}
    resp, err :=  client.Do(r)
    FatalIfErr("[UPLOAD]: %s", err)
    
    // for debug
    fmt.Println("---REQUEST---")
    fmt.Printf("URL: %#v\n", resp.Request.URL)
    fmt.Printf("URL: %s\n", resp.Request.URL.String())
    
    for k,v := range resp.Request.Header{
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", k,v)
    }
    
    fmt.Println("---RESPONSE---")
     for k,v := range resp.Header{
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", k,v)
    }
    
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    
    content, err := Unzip(resp)
    FatalIfErr("[UPLOAD]: %s", err)
    result, err = ioutil.ReadAll(content)
    FatalIfErr("[UPLOAD]: %s", err)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(result))
    return result, err
     
}


func main(){
    var err error
    var result []byte
    
    urlPath := "https://translate.yandex.net/doc/api/v1.0/translate"
    filePath := "A.H. AND OTHERS v. GERMANY_[001-203947].docx"
    
    queryValues := &url.Values{
      "sid": []string{"03746afa.5fba43a4.0ce12049.2d"},
      "srv": []string{"tr-doc"},
      "ui": []string{"ru"},
      "tr_dir": []string{"en-ru"},
      "doc_ext": []string{"docx"},
    }

    result, err = Upload(urlPath, queryValues, filePath)
    FatalIfErr("[UPLOAD]: %s", err)
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("tr.docx", result, 0644)
    FatalIfErr("[UPLOAD]: %s", err)
}
```

P.S. Сессионный sid, указанный в коде будет работать ровно неделю. Затем вам придется извлечь новый со страницы яндекса, чтобы сделать запрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос отменяется. Проблема была в банальной ошибке указания полного пути до файла в windows среде (двойные слэши - ну вот почему нельзя как Python просто префикс r"любой путь" указывать?) и игнорировании ошибки открытия файла.

Comment: «Как *Python*» — это [через обратные кавычки](https://play.golang.org/p/ULJUx6BzLoz).  Изучите вопрос прежде чем критиковать :-P !

Comment: Не нужно восклицаний. Я не критиковал. Про действие обратных кавычек не подумал. Спасибо, что напомнили.